# how to install gcc 4.4 on mac

Tags: macos, gcc, homebrew

I tried using brew  to install gcc 4.4 on mac using `brew install gcc44` but i got this error

```
Error: No available formula with the name "gcc44" 
==> Searching for a previously deleted formula...
Warning: homebrew/core is shallow clone. To get complete history run:
git -C "$(brew --repo homebrew/core)" fetch --unshallow

Error: No previously deleted formula found.
==> Searching for similarly named formulae...
==> Searching local taps...
 Error: No similarly named formulae found.
==> Searching taps...
==> Searching taps on GitHub...
```

Comment: Is there a reason you want to install such an old version?

Comment: The nearest you can get is `brew install gcc@4.6`

Comment: List available versions of gcc using `brew search gcc`. As you can see 4.4 is not available. 4.6 is the oldest, except for apple-gcc42.